# How to store FCM and GCP in server and call it on Android apps?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have this android apps which are using FCM key and maps api api key (GCP).

this apps contain code which make the FCM and GCP key exposed when i tried to upload it on play console.

in other word, this app hardcoded the app key in the client-side app.

i know the secure way to store those key are on the server, but i am struggling as to find how to apply that and call the api key in my client app because if the api key didnt include in the android app, this app wont function normally.

here are some code to provide.

```
    public String getUrl(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode, boolean isAlternative, Context context) {

        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode="+mode
                + "&key="+ BuildConfig.Gkey;

        if (isAlternative)
            url += "&alternatives=true";

        Log.e("getUrl", url);
        return url;
    }
```

i tried to store it in the gradle.properties and also local properties, but play console can also detect my api key.

is there any tutorial to store those key and how to call it from server in my android app.